# Looking for a Swift sample to implement Split View Controllers with Core Data, search controller

Tags: swift, core-data, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I would appreciate if anyone like to share a sample SWIFT project to implement split view controllers with core data, search controller and tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few Youtube videos which I though might be helpful.

This is from [Phone Tuts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x42Ac7ItT6s)

This is the [Stanford](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjl2gc70YHM) one. From my POV this is the best option since they dive deeper than the other tutorials and the professor shows you step by step ways of doing the Split View.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Emil, Above links are very good startup sources, thank you.  Looking for some code samples specifically where Split View and Core Data are used together.